# Dependency Injection in Symfony Commands in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

Let's say I have the following Symfony Command in TYPO3:

```
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    public function __constructor(string $name=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How is it possible to pass a class via dependency injection to the constructor without using the ObjectManager?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your TYPO3 version. With v10 TYPO3 uses PSR-11 and therefore should provide Dependency Injection for Commands.

Prior to that version that's not possible. I would suggest to move your own logic out of the command into dedicated classes. These could be loaded via ObjectManager and therefore use Dependency Injection already.

That approach would separate your logic from framework architecture (commands).

Comment: I am using v10.3, but unfortunately it didn't work. I moved my logic outside the command but still wanted to use DI as it feels cleaner.

Comment: Sorry, didn't play with commands in v10 yet, so no experience with DI in that area, but in general it should be possible somehow. Maybe you need to whitelist your command in Services.yaml.

Comment: There has been a recent change with typo 10.3, that involves DI and commands: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Feature-89139-AddDependencyInjectionSupportForConsoleCommands.html